# Skipping Every N th line while reading from file

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to read a file which contains data in the form,

```
0 160 76 160
0 320 11 320
0 960 470 960
960
0 12 6 12
0 24 7 24
0 1500 302 1500
3000
0 70 33 70
0 140 60 140
0 784 74 784
3920
```

I want to skip every 4th line(e.g 4, 8, 12, ..etc) which contains single value.
I tried this way,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("demofile.txt"));
int linenum = 0;
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
  if(linenum != 0 && linenum % 4 == 0){
     linenum++;
     continue;
  }
  else{
     String str = scan.nextLine();
     StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, " ");
     //Extract four tokens from single line
     String a = st.nextToken();
     String b = st.nextToken(); // This line throws java.util.NoSuchElementException
     //and so on..
     //other stuff
     ...
     linenum++;
  }
}
```

However its not working,I'm getting following Error trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:332)
at ReadDemo.main(ReadDemo.java:48) //line 48  is second `st.nextToken()` in above code
```

indicating that I am reading past the end of the file,
Whats wrong with above logic?
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?!

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program?  Generally the exception will tell you which line it is being thrown on.  You should start there.

Comment: When `linenum % 4 == 0`, you're incrementing the line number, but you're not actually skipping any lines.  Your `if` branch will need to read something from the file and throw it out.

Comment: lineNum should be initialized to 1

Comment: `st.nextToken()` is throwing Exception, I'll modify the code for clear understanding.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Strange!! May I know, what is off-topic in this question? That file format or java program?

Comment: @anycard No its not working on initializing it to 1

Comment: Your code is not skipping the line; it's just increasing the linenum every 4th line; you also need to call `scan.nextLine()` in that `if` block. Your expression also has a problem; you're skipping the the fifth line instead of the fourth line. Rewrite it as `if ((linenum + 1) % 4 == 0)`

Comment: I'm voting to reopen, but can you please post the exact, *complete* error message rather than just indicating which line is the problem using a comment?

Comment: @AdiInbar I've added the error trace. Please see modified post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start linenum at 1 and your program will work.
Also, the incrementing of linenum is poorly implemented.
Try somthing like this:

```
linenum = 1;
while (scan.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    if ((linenum % 4) > 0)
    {
        StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
        ... blah
    }

    ++linenum;
}
```